# Outlook.com doesn't work under Linux

Tags: networking

I'm facing a very strange problem.

I'm an employee in a little company, and on the company network, I can't access my mails on outlook.com.

As the problem is pretty strange, I will be as clear as possible:

- I'm running under Ubuntu
- Outlook.com **works in my home's network**
- Normally, I go to outlook.com and since the server recognizes me, it redirects me immediately to the web-app.
- But on the office network, the redirect screen after auto-authentication is blank and the web-app is not loaded.
- This is not a cache issue.
- Same behavior on Opera, Chrome, Chromium, Firefox.
- No errors in JavaScript console.
- But it works perfectly on Windows.
- The ISP box firewall is in its original configuration.
- The network configuration of my PC is in its original configuration.
- outlook.com works on all other Windows computers of the company.
- But **does not works on Linux computers**, so it is not related to my computer.
- I also have Debian on my PC, same problem.
- Yes, the ISP box has been restarted many times.

An engineer in my company tried to help me but he did not find anything.

Here the blank page's DOM I receive after authentication:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function rd(){window.location.replace("https://mail.live.com?id=64855&owa=1&owasuffix=owa%2f");}
            function OnBack(){}function OnNext(){}
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:rd();"></body>
</html>
```

And nothing more happens. Chrome displays its counterclockwise loader icon during a minute or two, Firefox nothing.

Comment: Just want to clarify a point. In your description you have mentioned "My PC" also you have mentioned that the issue seems to persists in the company's network. Just want to know whether you have tried with any other PC (apart from yours) in company's network? If not, how about other PC's?

Comment: Yes! I said that outlook.com works fine on all other Windows PCs. But it doesn't works on all other Linux PCs (Debian & Ubuntu).
But I can access my mails on all other networks - my home, university, bars, libraries...

Comment: Have you tried performing this redirect manually? Just paste the URL into your browser: `https://mail.live.com?id=64855&owa=1&owasuffix=owa%2f`. On a side-node, outlook.com is hit or miss in anything except Internet Explorer (guess why).

Comment: Same situation here. At home, I have gmail but people here need to access outlook.com, from my Ubuntu 14.04, a blank page, from Windows 8 and 7, loads OK. Interesting to note the following: A Windows XP SP 3 Virtual Machine, with Ubuntu 14.04 as host, do not load outlook.com either, same behavior, including in IE 8. Something in the Linux OS is preventing the connection. I suspecting the CA certificates, due to this old Chrome bug report: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/RkzXz5sXThU

Comment: In that old bug report. An user tried many files, until he found the culprit, a css file did not load due to failed https connection. If the css file url was pasted in the browser address bar, you had the option to add an exception, but as it was loaded as resource, the failed safe connection error was hidden, only visible if you turn on the developer tools. That css file is not the cause any more, but may be any other file now. I tried to use the developer tools to see the console log and the network log, but nothing there, console is blank and network only tries to load two urls.

Comment: The following url is the last one to be logged by the Firefox network monitoring tool: https://col125.mail.live.com/default.aspx, no http status code, it means the loading process stops there. https://mail.live.com/ is the first one, it returns code 302.

Comment: Interesting, but in my case, this was probably not (or not only) a client problem: later, we changed the box and even our ISP. And now it works perfectly. The problem was never solved by finding its source, but one thing is sure : this is very strange, as you saw it. That's why my OP was... a little confuse. Good luck!

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem for years now. Probably it's not a matter of the linux (I have tried ubuntu and debian too), but more likely that Microsoft is blocking it or something so.
Every browser I have tried has this issue (Firefox, Chrome/Chromium, Opera, Vivaldi) - nothing loads.
However though, I am able to reach the Calendar and Contacts webapps but not Office WebApps, OneDrive and Outlook inbox. In my point of view it's not a matter of the system itself, but Microsoft's attitude towards Linux. Some friends of mine have also experienced the same problem; but on Windows it still wo

Comment: This cannot be Linux discrimination, since it was working at home, and as soon as we changed the ISP's box, it was working again.